# R: nested groupings and total counts via dplyr?

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I'm trying to practice using the `dplyr` package in R with a data frame called 
fruit_eaten like so:

```
person,fruit
Alice,apple
Alice,apple
Alice,apple
Alice,orange
Bob,apple
Bob,banana
Bob,grape
Bob,grape
Bob,grape
Cheryl,orange
Cheryl,orange
Cheryl,kiwi
Donald,apple
Donald,apple
Donald,grape
Donald,grape
```

I would like to do the following with `dplyr`:

For each type of fruit, calculate who ate *the most* of it (so this is not a simple count, I want to find the maximum count) and how many to produce this table:

```
| fruit  | who_ate_most | how_many |
|--------|--------------|----------|
| apple  | Alice        | 3        |
| orange | Cheryl       | 2        |
| banana | Bob          | 1        |
| grape  | Bob          | 3        |
| kiwi   | Cheryl       | 1        |
```

In addition, I'm not sure how to deal with situations where two or more people all ate the same maximum number of a fruit.

Similarly, I'm trying to make a table that lists each person and the fruit that they ate the most of and how many:

```
| person | ate_most_of | how_many |
|--------|-------------|----------|
| Alice  | apple       | 3        |
| Bob    | grape       | 3        |
| Cheryl | orange      | 2        |
| Donald | apple       | 2        |
```

Of course a similar problem for this second output table is what to do if a person ate the same maximum number of more than one fruit?

I am aware of the `group_by()` function in `dplyr`, but looks like I have more than one "group" here. And how do I get that maximum count for the "how_many" columns in both tables?

P.S. The original data in comma delimited format (pastebin link [here](http://pastebin.com/13wRgcuq)).

Comment: Can you provide the input in a format that can be fed to R code as opposed to SQL output? This can be done, and I can help. But, not going to spend time formatting text to get it into R.

Comment: @Gopala I've added CSV format at the end of the original post plus a pastebin link, does that work? Thanks!!

Comment: @Frank Good point, tie added for Donald.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each type of fruit, calculate who ate the most of it (this is not a simple count, rather, a maximum count):

```
df %>%
  count(fruit, person) %>%
  top_n(1)

#    fruit person     n
#   (fctr) (fctr) (int)
# 1  apple  Alice     3
# 2 banana    Bob     1
# 3  grape    Bob     3
# 4   kiwi Cheryl     1
# 5 orange Cheryl     2

df %>%
  count(person, fruit) %>%
  top_n(1)

#   person  fruit     n
#   (fctr) (fctr) (int)
# 1  Alice  apple     3
# 2    Bob  grape     3
# 3 Cheryl orange     2
# 4 Donald  apple     2
# 5 Donald  grape     2
```

Noting that `count` is a wrapper for `tally`|`summarise`|`n` which does the `group_by` for you. Notice the difference in the ordering of the underlying `group_by`. Also note that each summary (the underlying `n()` summarization) peels off one level of grouping.

---

Per the comments about getting one record per tie, we can use `toString` as suggested by @Frank. In addition, we can "keep" `n` by extracting the `first()` value from its vector:

```
df %>%
  count(person, fruit) %>%
  top_n(1) %>%
  summarise(     n = first(n),
            fruits = toString(fruit))

#   person     n       fruits
#   (fctr) (int)        (chr)
# 1  Alice     3        apple
# 2    Bob     3        grape
# 3 Cheryl     2       orange
# 4 Donald     2 apple, grape
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been thinking about the group_by() function but should have looked at count(). Is there a strategy for dealing with ties?

Comment: How do you want to deal with ties?

Comment: One option is adding `%>% summarise(fruit = toString(fruit))` at the end (for the second table). I bet there's some tidyr thing for it, too.

Comment: You can use `top_n(1)` instead of `filter(n == max(n))` to get the top rows in each group. Or, any number of top rows.

Comment: I'm not sure how to best deal with ties to "future proof" the output for possible downstream analyses. In the case of Donald for the second output, would it be advisable to produce a vector with elements "apple" and "grape" in the fruit column, or have two roles for Donald?

Comment: @hpy Depends what you want to do with the result. It's sort of a subjective, open-ended question. You might try the folks in the r public chat room for advice: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: @Frank Didn't know about the chat room, awesome resource. Thank you so much! Marking as solved.